# A rather curious equality: is this true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I came across (coincidentally) two integral evaluations, which seem to agree according to numerical tests. It did not seem easy to convert one into the other.

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
>   $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{\arcsin x}x\right)^3dx
> =\frac34\pi\int_0^1\left(2\,\text{arctanh}\, x +\frac{\log(1-x^2)}x\right)dx.$$

Comment: Maple verifies it:
L:= int((arcsin(x)/x)^3,x=0..1);
$$ L:= -\frac{\pi^3}{16}+\frac{3\pi\,\ln  \left( 2 \right)}{2} $$
R:= 3/4*Pi*int(2*arctanh(x)+log(1-x^2)/x,x=0..1);
$$ R := \frac{3 \pi \left(-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+2 \ln(2)\right)}{4} $$
normal(L-R);
$$ 0$$

Comment: The question, then, is whether the initial two integrals are equal simply because they are both equal to a third thing, or whether there is a direct transformation.

Comment: @MyNinthAccount : The OP's question actually is "Is this true?" Also, I think that, formally speaking, there is no such thing as "a direct transformation". However, there may be a **simpler** "direct" proof of $A=B$ than an "indirect" proof of $A=C\ \&\ C=B$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: that'd be my wish.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proposed equality is true.

---

Details: To find 
$$l:=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\arcsin x}x\right)^3\,dx
=-\frac{1}{16} \pi  \left(\pi ^2-24 \ln2\right),
$$
make the substitution $t=\arcsin x$ and repeatedly integrate by parts to kill the powers of $t$ and reduce this integral to 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin t\,dt=-\frac\pi2\,\ln2,
$$ 
by 
[formula 4.225.3, page 531, of Gradshteyn--Ryzhik](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwi9tu7I57PkAhUEOKwKHZBWDdUQFjADegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffisica.ciens.ucv.ve%2F~svincenz%2FTISPISGIMR.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01xV-Pb5aQAUw6cJvOGtpR).

To find 
$$r_1:=\int_0^1 2\,\text{arctanh}\, x\,dx
=\ln4,
$$
integrate by parts to find an antiderivative of $\text{arctanh}$. Alternatively, expand $\text{arctanh}\, x$ into the Maclaurin series (using $\text{arctanh}'x=\frac1{1-u}=1+u+u^2+\dots$ with $u=x^2$) and integrate termwise, to get 
$$r_1/2=\sum_1^\infty\frac1{(2j-1)2j}
=\sum_1^\infty\Big(\frac1{2j-1}-\frac1{2j}\Big)
=\sum_1^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k=\ln2.
$$

To find 
$$r_2:=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}x\,dx
=-\frac12\,\sum_1^\infty\frac1{j^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12},
$$
expand $\ln(1-x^2)$ into the Maclaurin series (by using the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1-u)$) and integrate termwise.
Now one can see that $l=\frac{3\pi}4\,(r_1+r_2)$, that is, the equality holds.

Comment: You do both RHS integrals termwise in expansions, and reduce the LHS to $\smash{\int\ln\sin}$. As Euler also did the latter [termwise in a (“Fourier”) expansion](//hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/when-was-eulers-log-sine-integral-first-computed-by-real-methods), I wonder (without having checked anything) if maybe the OP’s sought transformation could also be seen “termwise”? Alternatively, *loc. cit.* may also suggest looking into deformation of appropriate contour integrals.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler : Thank you for the nice "Euler--Fourier" reference.

Comment: Good resolution, thanks.